# Run Autodesk Applications in cloud

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

One of my friends have the following requirement.

He wants to run an Autodesk application, and build a model. For a Windows desktop machine (core i7 with 16 GB RAM), it takes hours to complete the task.

Hence I suggested to look at AWS or Azure as a solution. I was searching for a complete solution for his usecase and failed.

It is possible to create an instance which can be accessed as a remote desktop machine and install software that we prefer?

How can we access the GUI desktop of that machine and work similar to a usual desktop machine?

Appreciate if you can provide a comprehensive good tutorial on this case.

Thanks,

Comment: yes, you can do that, but whats the price expectation? It's not exactly cheap, especially if you need GPU. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-hero-tutorial

Comment: what would be the price for instance similar to i7 6th Gen, 16GB ram, SSD disk?

Comment: why do you need similar?? generally around 1$\h, not counting storage\network costs

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was asking about an instance similar to a desktop machine having those specifications.
Anyway I'll contact Azure support, if I need further clarifications.